# Cant access global variable in actionPeformed method in java Swing application

Tags: java, onclicklistener

I have application where on Jbutton click i create new JFrame with its own class and import file

When i read file i passed that file to  method of my MainGui class where i parse data and store it in array of objects which is global field.

When i click on another button from MainGui, i cant access that array of objets and none of its fields(i get nullPointerException)

Here is my code:

MainGui Class

```
public class MainGui implements ActionListener {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;       
GrupaArtikala[] objektiArtikli; // ARRAY OF OBJECTS
JPanel centerPanel  = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
private final int MAX_TABLES = 8;   
JButton buttonImport;
JButton [] buttonsTables = new JButton[MAX_TABLES]; 
String tables[] = { 
                    "Grupa artikala",
                    "Osnovna mera",
                    "Jedinica mere",
                    "Naknada",
                    "Popust",
                    "Artikal",
                    "Normativ",
                    "Normativ stavka",
                     }; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainGui window = new MainGui();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });         
}   

private void createAndShowPodesavanja() {
     GuiFileChooser guiPodesavanja= new GuiFileChooser(); // HERE I CREATE NEW FRAME
     guiPodesavanja.initialize();
     guiPodesavanja.setVisible(true);       
    // this.setVisible(false);      
}

public MainGui() {      
    initialize();
}

public void pars(String file) {         
     try {
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));               

            int startArtikitag = content.indexOf(":ISSI");              
            int endArticalTag = content.indexOf("#TABLENAME:OSNOVNA_MJERA");                
            String gupaArtikalaString = content.substring(startArtikitag + 5, endArticalTag - 15);              
            System.out.println(gupaArtikalaString);

            String[] lines =gupaArtikalaString.split(System.lineSeparator());                               

           objektiArtikli = new GrupaArtikala[lines.length];                
            for(int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {                 
                objektiArtikli[i] = new GrupaArtikala(lines[i]);    // HERE I INITALIAZE ARRAY OF OBJECTS
            }

            System.out.println("rec u konstruktoru lokalno " +  objektiArtikli[1].getId());                     
            System.out.println("rec u gobalno" + objektiArtikli[1].getId());            
            // HERE I HAVE OUTPUT 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    initialize();        
}

private void initialize() {         
    frame = new JFrame("FreshPos baza podataka");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    // Main paneel      
    panel = new JPanel();       
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10) );
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    //West panel;
    JPanel panelWest = new JPanel(new GridLayout(14,0,0,2));            
    panelWest.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(200,0,10,10) );
    panel.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);    

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TABLES; i++) {          
        buttonsTables[i] = new JButton(tables[i]);          
        //buttonsTables[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, buttonsTables[i].getMinimumSize().height));
        //buttonsTables[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));
        panelWest.add(buttonsTables[i]);                    
    }       

    buttonsTables[0].addActionListener(this); // HERE I CLICK ON BUTTON!!       

    //North panel;      
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(); // Donji layout za dugmice        
    northPanel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0) );
    panel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //northPanel.setBackground(Color.green);        
     buttonImport = new JButton("Importuj datoteku");
    buttonImport.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,40));

    northPanel.add(buttonImport, BorderLayout.WEST);    
    buttonImport.addActionListener(this); 
    JButton ButtonRecord = new JButton("Snimi datoteku");
    ButtonRecord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,40));
    northPanel.add(ButtonRecord, BorderLayout.WEST);        
}

    public void showGrupaArtikala () {      

    centerPanel.removeAll();    
    centerPanel.updateUI();                 
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);      
    panel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);            
    JPanel southInCentral = new JPanel(); // Donji layout za dugmice    
    centerPanel.add(southInCentral, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
    JButton buttonDodaj = new JButton("Dodaj");
    //buttonDodaj.setLocation(100, 100);        
    buttonDodaj.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,40));
    southInCentral.add(buttonDodaj);        
    JButton buttonIzmeni = new JButton("Izmeni");
    buttonIzmeni.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,40));
    southInCentral.add(buttonIzmeni);       
    JButton butonObrisi = new JButton("Obrisi");
    butonObrisi.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,40));
    southInCentral.add(butonObrisi);            

    // Center layout in central panel           
    JPanel centralInCentral = new JPanel(); //
    centerPanel.add(centralInCentral);  

    // Jtable               
   String[] columnNames = {"ID,",
                    "SIFRA",
                    "NAZIV",
                    "IKONA_ID"};    

   Object[][] data = {
                    {"Kathy", "Smith",    "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                    {"John", "Doe",  "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                    {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                    {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                    {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
                };    

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);       
    //JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)      
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);    
    centerPanel.add(scrollPane);

    panel.repaint();
    panel.revalidate();         

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
          if(e.getSource() == buttonsTables[0]) {                             
              System.out.println("String here "+ objektiArtikli[1].getId()); // HERE OUTPUT IS NULL
              showGrupaArtikala();
          } else if (e.getSource() == buttonImport) {
              System.out.println("aa");               
              createAndShowPodesavanja();                 
          }         
    }
```

}

GuiFileChooser Class

```
public class GuiFileChooser {

private JFrame frame;   
JTextField jEditText;

public GuiFileChooser () {  

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GuiFileChooser window = new GuiFileChooser();                   
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });     
}

private void fileChoose(ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();  
    int i=chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

     if(i==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){             
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();     
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();      
        MainGui m = new MainGui();
        m.pars(filename);   // HERE I CALL pars(filename) in MainGui method     
        jEditText.setText(filename);    

     }                                  
}

void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Dodaj datoteku");
    frame.setBounds(750, 350, 460, 150); // top     
    //Dimension d = new Dimension(440, 200);
    // Dimension d1 = new Dimension(451, 451);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    //frame.setPreferredSize(d);
    //frame.setMinimumSize(d);
    // frame.setMaximumSize(d1);
    // frame.setSize(450, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton lblNaziv = new JButton("Izaberite datoteku..");     
    lblNaziv.setBounds(10 ,10, 160, 25); // horizontalna margina , vertikalna margina , visina, duzina
    lblNaziv.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            fileChoose(evt);                                
        }           
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNaziv);

    jEditText = new JTextField();   
    jEditText.setBounds(180 ,10, 250, 25); // horizontalna margina , vertikalna margina , visina, duzina        
    frame.getContentPane().add(jEditText);

    JButton buttonOk = new JButton("OK");   
    buttonOk.setBounds(180,50, 100, 30); // horizontalna margina , vertikalna margina ,
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonOk);
    buttonOk.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            frame.dispose();                                
        }           
    });

}

public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    frame.setVisible(b);        
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a [tour], read [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, you probably want `for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)`

Comment: One thing I don't see is you calling that method `pars(File)`. Hence, when you never initialize the array it will be null.

Comment: i updated please take a look

Comment: i initaize it in pars(File) method

Comment: Here's one of your problems (besides many design related problems): in your file chooser you have `MainGui m = new MainGui(); m.pars(filename); ` - that will fill the array of a _new_ instance of `MainGui` and of the one that the chooser was opened from. Pass that instance to the chooser for some easy fix (the design could be a lot better but giving advice on that would be out of scope here).

Comment: Hmm can you please give me some code how to pass the instance to chooser.

Comment: When i pass instance to FileChooser, i never get if statments public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
   
   System.out.println("u actionperfomed");  
    
     if(e.getSource() == MainGui.this.buttonsTables[0]) {  // now never get called
      System.out.println(" u if:");
      System.out.println("String here "+ MainGui.this.objektiArtikli[1].getId()); // Here is null
      showGrupaArtikala();
     } else if (e.getSource() == buttonImport) {
      System.out.println("aa");      
      createAndShowPodesavanja();      
     }   
  }

Comment: Ok it work when i pass instance it worsk, but one question please . when i do  MainGui m = new MainGui(); m.pars(filename) in my constructor we initialise gui components over so why we use gui chooser instance gui when we load gui from new instance>?]\